# Should I wait patiently if the professor asked me to wait for a few weeks?

Tags: postdocs, funding, presentation, interview

I am in my final year of PhD and submiting thesis in June. I had an interview for a Postdoc position about 2 months ago and gave an on site talk to the lab. The professor asked me to talk to each lab member individually to ask about lab culture, salary and so on. The professor and I then had  another interview and she briefly talked about the project I would be doing. When I asked about when I can know if I can get an offer, she asked me to await for like a month. She told me it's quite positive and very keen on taking me. But she has to think about grants and funding as she will be taking a couple of postdocs. After waiting for one month, she requested to wait for a few more months for her to be certain.

Only a few labs are available in the country I am applying for. So I don't want to apply for other labs and get rejected or rejecting their offer if any.

So should I just wait and see how she will reply before applying more? What is my chance of being accepted? Thanks!

Comment: It's perfectly normal (recommended, even) to apply for multiple jobs at the same time.

Comment: How did these interviews come to be? Was there a position announced for which you applied?

Comment: It was a vacancy when I applied. She told me she's thinking of hiring 2 postdocs. And as I haven't submitted thesis, my starting time in her lab is still quite far from now so she wants to settle almost-expired grants and other candidates. 
A few of her lab members hinted that as I an allowed to talk to them, I might have higher chance. Now I am kinda in dilemma ..

Comment: To me that renders her statement about funding a bit fishy - it seems quite unlikely that a position gets announced when the funding is not settled yet. Perhaps she sees you as a good candidate, but not a top candidate, and she wants to wait if she can find someone better.

Comment: In last email, she said she thinks it would be fine but she wants to be certain. This made me a bit hopeful. I like that lab as they do what I am excited about. I agree I should start looking for other jobs while awaiting her reply.

Comment: "she wants to be certain" -> If you were a top candidate for her, she would make sure to hire you fast, so that you're off the market. So I agree that it's a good idea to start looking for other jobs.

Answer (score 2):

> she has to think about grants and funding as she will be taking a couple of postdocs. After waiting for one month, she requested to wait for a few more months for her to be certain.

This professor seemingly has no money to hire you. You should look elsewhere, whilst maintaining contact. If she gets money, it seems you are amongst those she'll consider hiring.

Comment: That's one option, but not the only one.